# Super tokens multiple user pools

Tags: authentication, permissions

In aws cognito we can use multiple user pools , is there anything similar in Supertokens , I could not find related to storing users in different collection / pool is the documentations

Answer (score 1):

SuperTokens doesn't support multiple user pools at the moment (as of 11th June, 2022). However, it is on the roadmap.

In the meantime, you have the following options:

- You can spin up one instance of the core, per user pool, connected to its own db. You would also need to spin up one backend server to connect to one instance of the core.
- You can simulate a user pool by modifying the primary key identifying the user. For example, let's say you have two user pools (p1 and p2), and you are using email password login, where the email is the primary identifying info of a user. You can override the backend recipe functions to modify the email being sent to supertokens core to include the pool ID. So for example, if a user's email is `user1@example.com`, then you could change it to `user1+p1@example.com` if they belong to user pool 1. So this way, even if the user uses the same email in the other app, it would identify them as a different user (their email being `user1+p2@example.com` in pool 2). Whilst this approach may be slightly more complex to implement, it requires just one core, connected to one db.